# Compared to emacs, what are the drawbacks of emacsclient?

Tags: emacs

As we know, `emacsclient` is very fast to launch compared to `emacs`, does it mean we can always alias `emacsc` to `emacsclient`? If not, why? On another word, What's the drawbacks of `emacsclient`?

Comment: You can't run emacsclient if eamcs server isn't running.

Comment: it's only fast because emacs is already running as a server. There are no drawback, it is a method in which your frame can be opened and closed while the core process does not stop.

Comment: @manandearth (or choroba): Please consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running emacs as a daemon , each client (a frame of emacs) loads immidiately, since the core process is already running. It also keeps running when you close the frame with `C-x 5 0` which is also convinient as you are not prompted to save buffers and can open and close frames as you wish.

Yet, loading the server at first with `emacs --daemon`  takes no less than loading emacs normally.

For the convinience of loading read about setting up in [emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon). It is a comprehensive account of the different methods in different operating systems.